# VB.NET hide NotifiyIcon ContextMenuStrip when click somewhere else

Tags: vb.net

My Form include Notify icon with ContexMenu. ContextMenu is automatically closed when click on any item (AutoClose=True). But if I click anywhere else (away from context menu), ContextMenu remains visible. How to hide it in this case?

Found one answer, that hiding context menu when click somewhere else is standard behavior of context menu. In my case it doesnt work :).

I tried to use ContextMenuStrip Leave or LostFocus event to hide but this didnt work.

To show context menu:

```
Private Sub NotifyIcon1_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
                        Handles NotifyIcon1.DoubleClick
    NotifyIcon1.ContextMenuStrip.Show(MousePosition)
End Sub
```

To hide context menu I tried:

```
Private Sub ContextMenuStrip_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
                        Handles ContextMenuStrip.Leave
    NotifyIcon1.ContextMenuStrip.Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub ContextMenuStrip_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
                        Handles ContextMenuStrip.LostFocus
    NotifyIcon1.ContextMenuStrip.Hide()
End Sub
```

UPDATE: This works:

```
Private Sub ContextMenuStrip_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
                         Handles ContextMenuStrip.MouseLeave
    NotifyIcon1.ContextMenuStrip.Hide()
End Sub
```

Could be used as temp solution, but original question still open.